# Login flutuante e Login query

Tags: php, html

Quero criar um retangulo com login sobre a página que estou a trabalhar. Nao quero que o login vá para uma página só com o login.

Isso é possível ?

Outra duvida e fazer com cada login veja uma query especifica. Isso é possivel?

Comment: Quanto a primeira pergunta: **Sim**. E a segunda: **Sim**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto a primeira parte da sua dúvida você pode fazer com algo do tipo que montei agora, clique em "Executar trecho de código" para ver o código em ação:
(note que não mexi com nada de alinhamentos)

```js
$(function(){
  
  // Ao clicar para mostrar o formulário de login
  
  $("button.fazer-login").click(function(){
    $("#login-container").fadeIn("fast");
  });
  
  // Ao clicar para fechar o formulário de login
  
  $("button.fechar-login").click(function(){
    $("#login-container").fadeOut("fast");
  });
  
  // Se preferir que o login seja por AJAX
  
  $("#login-container #login").submit(function(e){
    
    // O e.preventDefault impede do formulário ser enviado para o faz_login.php, recarregando a página imediatamente
    
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'faz_login.php',
        data: $("#login").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          // Mostrar a resposta em um alert
          alert(data);
          // Ou se preferir fazer o debug pelo console
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#ECECEC;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#login-container{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
}

#login{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  text-align:center;
  
  margin-top:100px;  
}

#login input[name=usuario]{
  margin:0px 0 5px;
}

#login input[type=submit]{
  margin:15px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Formulário de login -->

<div id="login-container" style="display:none">
  <form id="login" method="post" action="faz_login.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" name="usuario" /><br/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" /><br/>
    <button class="fechar-login">Fechar login</button>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Conteúdo da página -->

Aqui é a sua página.<br/><br/>
<button class="fazer-login">Clique aqui para fazer login!</button>
```

Se você quiser que o formulário de login fique centralizado na vertical, irá ter que fazer ajustes no código.

**EDITADO**

Adicionei o código de ajax no evento de enviar o formulário. 
Agora no faz_login.php

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND senha = '".$senha."'";
$consulta = mysql_query($query);
$resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);

if($resultado[0]){
echo "Login realizado com sucesso!";
}
else{
echo "Dados incorretos.";
}

?>
```

Nesse código PHP você pode manipular a consulta da forma que preferir.

Comment: secalhar nao me expliquei bem mas depois do login dependendo do login utilizado mostrar uma query especifica. 
Se for o login 1 mostrar a query X 
Se for o login 2 mostrar a query Y

Comment: Depende da query (consulta) que você quer. A consulta vai ser realizada onde? No banco de dados ou dentro de um condição montada na hora no javascript?

Comment: um banco de dados Mysql

Comment: Você trabalha com PHP?

Comment: Sim so com php e Mysql

Comment: Nesse caso, vou editar a resposta acima.

Comment: Surgiu-me um problema a ver se me consegue ajudar nisto. 
é possivel fazer o login em fez de ser o botão..<button class="fazer-login">Clique aqui para fazer login!</button> usar isto : <img class="fazer-login" src="images/Consulta.PNG"  >

Comment: Sim, é só trocar o button pelo img e no jQuery, todas as chamadas para "button.fazer-login" você vai trocar para "img.fazer-login" ou simplesmente ".fazer-login".

Comment: a ver se me consegue ajudar. fiz isso mas nao acontece nada. Deixo aqui o codigo: http://jsfiddle.net/7yfs4rzr/

Comment: Você não pode esquecer de inicializar o jquery com "$(function(){". Fora isso sempre indenize o código para não esquecer de fechar tags do HTML. Aqui o jsfiddle editado: http://jsfiddle.net/7yfs4rzr/2/

Comment: boas, tive um tempo fora e agora fui novamente pegar nisso e o resultado é me mostrado numa pequena janela em vez de ser numa pagina nova ..

Answer (score 0):

Amigo você pode usar o dialog do JQuery. Abaixo segue o link:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form